# Level adjustments result different than preview

Tags: photoshop-cs5, image-manipulation

I am trying to create a starfield from a noise layer by using Image->Adjustments->Levels.
But when I've got to a setup with the result I want being visible in preview and I press *OK* to apply those changes permanently it's all turning into a brighter gray tone (which seems to be what PS does when I hit *Auto* instead of *OK*).

So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I sorted it out. The preview looks differently when zoomed out. Did it at 100% zoom and it worked out well.